# What is effect on /V1/order?searchCriteria api,when i delete some customer from magento admin panel?

Tags: magento-2.1, orders, rest-api

I have some issue in rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria API.If I deleted all customer from admin panel,then what is effect on rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria API.When i call this API it give response:"Requested product doesn't exist.".Please guide me.